# Simple XML Manipulations in perl

Tags: xml, perl

I know SO doesn't honor this type of questions, but I have invested a lot of time trying to choose the best XML manipulation library for perl and almost no expample I've found provides a clear understanding on how to insert values and print out the resulting xml to a string variable.

Here is my incoming XML without values:

```
my $GetLibByNameAndVersionEnvelope = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                                            <s:Body>
                                                <GetLibByNameAndVersion xmlns="LibService">
                                                    <name></name>
                                                    <version></version>
                                                </GetGridLibByNameAndVersion>
                                            </s:Body>
                                        </s:Envelope>';
```

I need to populate the name and the version nodes with test values. Please provide an example on how can I do this, so in a result, I have a string that containes a required XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Did you know that Perl has a whole set of modules specifically to deal with SOAP?  [This article](http://www.perl.com/pub/2001/01/soap.html) seems like a good place to start.

`XML::Twig` has a list of tutorials on [their website](http://www.xmltwig.org/).  I recommend [this tutorial](http://www.xmltwig.org/xmltwig/tutorial/index.html), which is old but will definitely cover all of the things you are interested in.

Also, CPAN documentation almost always has good simple examples of how to use a module.  [`XML::Twig`'s documentation certainly does](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.42/Twig.pm).  [So does `XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm).

Here is [an article on using `XML::Simple`](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/parsing-xml-documents-with-perls-xmlsimple/5363190).

Answer (score 3):

This is a SOAP request, right?

If it is just this one simple SOAP call that always looks the same, I'd suggest you use a **template engine**, put in **placeholders** and don't bother with XML modules at all. That's going to be a lot cheaper.

You can either use something like [Text::Template](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aTemplate) and put the template somewhere in your filesystem (so you can add it to version control) or simply add it to your code in the `DATA` section or even as a simple string variable. You could of course just put it in as a string like this:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $ua->post($url, <<"SOAP");
<s:Envelope>
  <s:Body>
    <GetLibByNameAndVersion xmlns="LibService">
      <name>$name</name>
      <version>$version</version>
    </GetGridLibByNameAndVersion>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
SOAP
```

That example is not very dynamic and you need to change the code if there are changes to the API. But for a very simple request, this is the quickest way. I feel sometimes this (or a template) is the way to go if you only have one rather simple method in your API.

Comment: As long as you can ensure that the replacement values are well formed XML (`<` and `&` escaped as `&lt;` and `&amp;`, no illegal characters, etc.)

Comment: @IanRoberts yes, of course your right about that, thank you. I was trying to put the focus on which way of approach is most suited for the scale of the problem.

Comment: +1 I agree that this is a good approach if it is something small and simple.  An XML parser will be more flexible if you are going to be doing a variety of requests, though.